# How do I convert a custom time format to time type in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, time-format

In the db table the time is imported into a field with the following format h:mmt (12 hour:minutes AM/PM designator). The field is a varchar type field.  I need to copy this into a field of type time.

I tried select CONVERT(time, '[Time]', 8) but I get the following error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Any ideas on how I can convert and copy the varchar time to a type of time?

Comment: problem not solved that means you should show few sample data as it is lying in DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove the quotes from around your column name, as you're trying to convert the word `[Time]` to a time, which won't work.

Try the below:

```
SELECT CONVERT(time, [Time], 8)
```